# Populate a cookie with a Django csrf token

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, cookies, django-rest-framework

i need to understand something.

I've a rest server on server A (django-rest-framework). An app on server B (angularjs) requests the rest server.
I want to add authentication. each time i request h`ttp://serverA/api-auth/login/`, it returns 403 because i don't pass the csrf token.

So, in my app.js, i've added :

```
.run(function($http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
});
```

now, fine, i can send the csrf token. 
My question is, how can i populate the cookie ? Do i have to do a get() to obtain the token before posting ? Because currently my cookie is empty :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `SessionAuthentication` method if you don't share the same domain. In your case the [OAuth2Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#oauth2authentication) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your angularjs code using jquery ajax to post, you can put the csrf token into the meta tag

```
<!--<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token}}">-->
```

Then setup your jquery ajax method to include the csrf token.

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        //var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }..............
});
```